# Can't upload custom header for large file to Backblaze

Tags: rclone, backblaze

I'm using `rclone` to upload a large file (~60Gb) to B2 storage. I also wanted to upload a custom header but it didn't work. It's worked fine if my file is small.

```bash
rclone --config rclone.conf --bwlimit 50M header-upload "X-Bz-Info-Uncompressed-Size: 10000000000" copy my-large-file "b2:my-bucket/"
```

I think if the file is too large, `rclone` will use [b2-upload-part API](https://www.backblaze.com/apidocs/b2-upload-part) instead of [b2-upload-file](https://www.backblaze.com/apidocs/b2-upload-file) for uploading and then this API didn't support custom header